# Can't seem to parse a xml file in android without getting a saxparser unexpected token error

Tags: java, android, xml

I've been fighting trying to parse a basic xml file in a little test android app.

The code I have is the following:

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.content);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
try {
      DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is,"UTF-8"); //Blows up right here.
      // Bunch more stuff here
}
```

My xml looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<main>
    <background>
        <defintion>This is a test</defintion>
    </background>
</main>
```

The problem is that when I try to parse this I get an `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT unprintable characters here ...@3:252 in java.io.InputStreamReader@411f3898)` error.
I googled around and all the other solutions I found don't seem to work.

I double checked that the file is UTF-8, and changed it's encoding back and forth between UTF-16 and UTF-8 (tried both with and without BOM) with notepad++, and updated the program to properly reflect this, but no matter what I do, I always get this error. I'm sure I must just be missing something very obvious, but no matter what series of combinations I try this always fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First put your **content.xml** file in **res/raw** folder then parse it as:

Your xml file **res/raw/content.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<main>
    <background>
        <defintion>This is a test</defintion>
    </background>
</main>
```

and parse it as:

```
  InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.content);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
            try {
                dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                try {
                    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is,"UTF-8");
                    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("main");

                    System.out.println("NodeList NodeList"+nl.getLength());

                } catch (SAXException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } //Blows up right here.
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem as yours. I finally found the solution:

Never put your xml in res/xml. The xml file will be encoded by android sdk, thus can't be read correctly. However, when you put it in res/raw, the xml file exported to the app will be intact.